# PHP sum items in an array by another ordinary item in same row

Tags: php, arrays

This is a simple example of an array I use in my php code. Original array is filled automaticly by queries.

I'm looking for an easy way to sum all "number" indexes in different rows with same "fruit" indexes. For example, if I want to count "Orange"s, I'll get "2" + "4" = "6" as result.

```
$fruit = array("Banana", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange");
$number = array("5", "3", "7", "2", "4"); 

$i = 0;

while($i < 5) {
    $myArray[$i] = array("fruit" => $fruit[$i], "number" => $number[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sum($res, $item){
    $key = $item['fruit'];
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $res)){
        $res[$key] = 0;
    }
    $res[$key] += $item['number'];
    return $res;
}

print_r(array_reduce($myArray, "sum", array()));
```

yields

```
Array
(
    [Banana] => 12
    [Apple] => 3
    [Orange] => 6
)
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Thanks.

Comment: did you combine the arrays first ? If so, please update your answer for future reference.

Comment: although this works exactly the way I want it to, it throws undefined index errors for each index before yielding desired result.

Comment: @Ahmet - that's right, one should for example check with `array_key_exists` first, I have included this into the answer

Comment: @PedroLobito - the array `myArray` is supposed to be in the same form as shown in the question